# Signal async completion warning upon upgrade to Gulp 4

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-4

I use Gulp to run one simple task in a non-JavaScript project. I'm trying to upgrade from 3.9.1 to 4.0 to get rid of the flood of "deprecated" and "security" warnings. Together with articles like [A quick guide for switching to gulp 4](https://codeburst.io/switching-to-gulp-4-0-271ae63530c0) I've upgraded locally, [dropped `gulp-util`](https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5) and ended up with this `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "redacted",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "ansi-colors": "^3.0.5",
    "fancy-log": "^1.3.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-zip": "^4.2.0",
    "temp": "^0.8.3"
  }
}
```

But I'm not a Node.js expert and I'm clearly missing something. My old style tasks:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var log = require('fancy-log');
gulp.task('hi', function() {
    log('Hello, World!');
});
```

… trigger:

```
PS D:\Redacted> gulp hi
[10:25:58] Using gulpfile D:\Redacted\gulpfile.js
[10:25:58] Starting 'hi'...
[10:25:58] Hello, World!
[10:25:58] The following tasks did not complete: hi
[10:25:58] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

If I inject `gulp.series()` and get rid of anonymous functions as the article recommends:

```
function hi() {
    log('Hello, World!');
}
gulp.task('hi', gulp.series(hi));
```

… then either the task runs twice or its output gets displayed twice (not sure) but the warning persists:

```
PS D:\Redacted> gulp hi
[10:28:47] Using gulpfile D:\Redacted\gulpfile.js
[10:28:47] Starting 'hi'...
[10:28:47] Starting 'hi'...
[10:28:47] Hello, World!
[10:28:47] The following tasks did not complete: hi, hi
[10:28:47] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

What bit am I missing? Is there a better upgrade guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old-fashioned syntax still works. I was apparently just missing a final call to the *done* callback that didn't seem to be required on Gulp/3:

```
gulp.task('hi', function(done){
    log('Hello, World!');
    done();
});
```

`gulp.series()` looks like overkill for running a single task.